# pandas DataFrame reshape by multiple column values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to free myself of JMP for data analysis but cannot determine the pandas equivalent of JMP's [Split Columns](http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Split_Columns.shtml) function.  I'm starting with the following DataFrame:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Level0': [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1], 'Level1': [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1], 'Vals': [1,3,2,4,1,6,7,5,3,3,2,8]})
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
    Level0  Level1  Vals
0        0       0     1
1        0       1     3
2        0       0     2
3        0       1     4
4        0       0     1
5        0       1     6
6        1       0     7
7        1       1     5
8        1       0     3
9        1       1     3
10       1       0     2
11       1       1     8
```

I can handle some of the output scenarios of JMP's function using the `pivot_table` function, but I'm stumped on the case where the `Vals` column is split by unique combinations of `Level0` and `Level1` to give the following output:

```
Level0   0       1
Level1   0   1   0   1
0        1   3   7   5
1        2   4   3   3
2        1   6   2   8
```

I tried `pd.pivot_table(df, values='Vals', columns=['Level0', 'Level1'])` but this gives mean values for the different combinations:

```
Level0  Level1
0       0         1.333333
        1         4.333333
1       0         4.000000
        1         5.333333
```

I also tried `pd.pivot_table(df, values='Vals', index=df.index, columns=['Level0', 'Level1']` which gets me the column headers I want but doesn't work because it forces the output to have the same number of rows as the original so the output has a lot of `NaN` values:

```
Level0   0       1
Level1   0   1   0   1
0        1 NaN NaN NaN
1      NaN   3 NaN NaN
2        2 NaN NaN NaN
3      NaN   4 NaN NaN
4        1 NaN NaN NaN
5      NaN   6 NaN NaN
6      NaN NaN   7 NaN
7      NaN NaN NaN   5
8      NaN NaN   3 NaN
9      NaN NaN NaN   3
10     NaN NaN   2 NaN
11     NaN NaN NaN   8
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit of workaround, but you can do:

```
df.pivot_table(index=df.groupby(['Level0', 'Level1']).cumcount(), 
               columns=['Level0', 'Level1'], values='Vals', aggfunc='first')
Out: 
Level0  0     1   
Level1  0  1  0  1
0       1  3  7  5
1       2  4  3  3
2       1  6  2  8
```

The idea here is that the index of the output is not readily available in the original DataFrame. You can get it with the following:

```
df.groupby(['Level0', 'Level1']).cumcount()
Out: 
0     0
1     0
2     1
3     1
4     2
5     2
6     0
7     0
8     1
9     1
10    2
11    2
dtype: int64
```

Now if you pass this as the index of the `pivot_table`, an arbitrary `aggfunc` (mean, min, max, first or last) should work for you as those index-column pairs have only one entry.

Comment: Thanks ayhan.  Works great.  Is the `aggfunc='first'` actually needed here?  I get the same answer without it.

Comment: @endangeredoxen The default is 'mean' for aggfunc. Since there is a single value, it actually doesn't matter. mean, min, max, first or last, any one of them will do.